# Absolute continuity and Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, derivatives

Let $\nu$ be a measure and $\mu$ a finite measure on $(X,\Sigma)$ with $\nu \ll \mu$. (All $\mu$-null sets are $\nu$-null.)

> Theorem:
>   There exists a measurable $f:X \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\forall S \in \Sigma$,
>   $$ \nu(S) = \int_S f\,d\mu $$

How to prove this theorem? If $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, the result follows from Radon- Nikodym theorem. The question hints that there exists a $\nu\,\sigma$-finite $U$ such that $\mu(U) \geq \mu(T)$ for all $\nu\,\sigma$-finite $T$. I tried to make $U$ the union of all $\sigma$-finite sets, but I cannot show that it is $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\alpha := \sup\{\mu (A)\mid A \,\sigma \text { finite w.r.t.} \nu\}.
$$

Show that there exists a nondecreasing sequence $(A_n)_n $ of $\nu $-sigma finite sets satisfying $\mu (A_n)\to \alpha $. Conclude that $A:=\bigcup_n A_n $ is $\nu $ sigma finite with $\mu (A)=\alpha $.

Conclude $\mu (B)=0$ for every $B \subset X\setminus A $ which is (sigma) finite with respect to $\nu $. Conversely, this means $\nu (B)=\infty $ if $B\subset X \setminus A $ satisfies $\mu (B )>0$.

Let $f $ be a Radon Nikodym derivative of $\nu $ w.r.t. $\mu $ on the sigma finite set $A $. Extend $f $ by $\infty $ on the complement of $A $. Show that $f $ does what you want.

Comment: Why is it so that for $B \cap X = \emptyset, \mu(B) > 0 \rightarrow \nu(B) = \infty$?

Comment: Otherwise, $A\cup B $ would be $\nu $ sigma finite (because of $\nu (B)<\infty $) with $\mu (A\cup B)=\mu (A)+\mu (B)>\alpha $, which is impossible.

Comment: Can you provide a full proof? I am confused how to prove your points